# Magento: Prepend block to Mage Head Block using controller_action_postdispatch event observer

Tags: magento

I am trying to use a custom event observer to observe the `controller_action_postdispatch` event and modify the response body directly by replacing opening head tag with + my custom block content. It is important that I make sure that it is an actual HTML page response, and not JSON or partial HTML in the case of an AJAX request. I would like to use the `controller_action_layout_render_before` event to determine that the head block is present, set a flag, which the previously mentioned observer method will check before modifying the response.

The use case is to safely prepend my custom block inside the head tag of every page, taking priority order over other head content such as meta tags, and script tags.

This is where I am at right now (not far, got a little lost)...

### config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    ...
    <global>
        ...
        <events>
            <controller_action_postdispatch>
                <observers>
                    <intercept_response>
                        <class>module/observer</class>
                        <method>interceptResponse</method>
                    </intercept_response>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch>
            <controller_action_layout_render_before>
                <observers>
                    <check_response>
                        <class>module/observer</class>
                        <method>checkResponse</method>
                    </check_response>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_render_before>
        </events>
    </global>
    ...
</config>
```

### Model/Observer.php

```
class My_Module_Model_Observer {

    protected $_isHead = FALSE;

    public function checkResponse() {
        if ( Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head')) {
            $_isHead = true;
        }
    }

    public function interceptResponse(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $block = $observer->getBlock();
    }

}
```

Comment: what's wrong? looks like all you need for observer, though i would put the events tag in the frontend

Comment: I cannot figure out how to successfully and safely prepend my block to the head block.  And I am also questioning if my check in the "checkResponse()" method is correct.

Comment: $observer-> loadLayout()->getBlock('head')->addBlock('yourBlock'), check the page xml to see the appropriate name for head etc.

Comment: It is important that I >prepend< my block to the head block, not append it.  Also, my storefront just seems to blow up when I call loadLayout() on my observer.

Comment: oh just remove it then, $observer-> loadLayout()->removeBlock('head')->addBlock('yourBlock')->addBlock('head'), but somehow i don't think prepend is the right word...

Comment: Strange thing is that my storefront blows up whenever calling loadLayout() on the observer.  Could it possibly be related to the 'controller_action_postdispatch' event?

Comment: It would be easier to rewrite Mage_Html_Page_Head class and assign a different phtml file, this way you would be add anything you want to the code.

Comment: @MagentoNinja -- I can successfully achieve my goal using the method you mention, but my concern is how it will interact with other custom modules that may affect the same functionality...

Comment: @cleong -- getLayout() on this observer returns NULL.

Comment: okay so observer can't be used directly for layout changes, try Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')

Answer (score 0):

I would probably approach the solution with a more standard approach than intercepting output. You can do what you want by appending a child block in the layout and outputting it with a custom template file in your theme.

**$theme/layout/local.xml**

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <!-- If you need a custom block, just swap in the type -->
        <block type="core/template" name="prepend-head" template="page/html/prepend-head.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

**$theme/template/page/html/head.phtml**

Somewhere near the top of the file just add `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('prepend-head') ?>`